# EXCEL VBA - Delete if a column exists

Tags: vba, excel

I have a requirement wherein, I need to delete that Particular column if that exists.

I am trying to locate the Particular column through column header.

This is my code,

```
If sColumnName = (WorksheetFunction.Match("RSD", Sheets("RS_Report").Rows(1), 0)) And sColumnName = True Then

DDC= WorksheetFunction.Match("RSD", Sheets("RS_Report").Rows(1), 0)

DFC= GetColumnLetter(DDC)

Range(DFC& 1 & ":" & DFC& lastrow).Select

Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
```

the GetColumnLetter and lastrow are my user defined functions and they return correct values. I am not sure how to check if a column exists or not. Kindly help me with this. Share your thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three ways to do this.

1) A for loop that looks to the extents of the header row for a specific string.
Pro: its easy
Con: the string has to be exact

something like

```
Dim string as yourString
Dim lColumn As Long
lColumn = ws.UsedRange.Columns.Count
yourString = whatever
for x = 1 to lcolumn
  if range(cells(1, 1), Cells(1, x)).Value = yourString
    Columns(x).EntireColumn.Delete
  End If
next
```

2) use the Range.Find method which you can learn about here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx

Here is a short rough example you can use as reference:

```
Sub Header_Format()
Dim rLastCell As Range
Set rLastCell = UpdateSheet.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=UpdateSheet.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False)
    With UpdateSheet.Range(Cells(4, 1), Cells(4, rLastCell.Column))
        .Copy MasterSheet.Cells(1, 1)
        .Copy RemovalSheet.Cells(1, 1)
    End With
End Sub
```

3) Finally there is using the match method, which someone spoke on already.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835873.aspx

Answer (score 3):

you can simply go like this

```
Dim col As Variant

With Sheets("RS_Report") '<--| reference relevant worksheet
    col = WorksheetFunction.Match("RSD", .Rows(1), 0) '<--| try searching its row 1 for wanted header text
    If Not IsError(col) Then .Columns(col).Delete '<--| if found then delete its entire column
End With
```

Comment: Nice, for  Another one ;)

Comment: @ShaiRado, thanks. You're climbing up quite fast, though!

Comment: @VBA_Begineer, out of curiosity can you tell me why did you choose Jaberwocky's solution? thank you

Comment: @user3598756 It was easy for me to understand with the explanations he gave, not because of any technical reasons. I am sure you both were absolutely right ! Thanks again

Comment: This is a better answer i believe. Though I used `Application.Match` apparently it has a better error handling capacity.